# Hardware Question: Tiny Fonts on 4k External Monitor Used with MacBook?

Tags: retina-display, multiple-monitors

I got a 27" 4k monitor to use with my 16" Retina Display MacBook. Fonts in the Finder and in most apps are tiny. In many cases they can be set to larger font sizes in the app or Finder settings -- but not in all cases. E.g. the fonts in the Finder menu bar, and sidebars in Finder windows, look like about 6-7pt, and extensive googling indicates there's no way to change it.

I guess I have to return this monitor and get a new one. I'd love to get a retina display but my company won't pay for it :)

The questions is -- what size/resolution monitor (up to 4k) will give me a good experience as an external monitor on a MacBook, with reasonable Finder font sizes?

**Update:** I went to the local Apple Store Genius bar, and was told that the anomaly may be because I'm plugging into an HDMI port on the monitor. Ideally it should be a USB-C port.  My monitor doesn't have a USB-C input port, but it has a DisplayPort, so the advice was to try plugging into that. I ordered a USB-C to DisplayPort cable and I'll try that tomorrow when the cable arrives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the DisplayPort fixed it. I can now access the text scaling options:

[image]